# How do I Extract Files Into Jar Files with Command Prompt on Windows 7?

Tags: command, extract, prompt

I want to extract files into a jar file, any way I can do it with command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert / compress files into a jar (foobar.jar)

```
jar cvf foobar.jar foo.txt bar.txt
```

to extract all of them

```
jar xvf foobar.jar
```

to extract only foo.txt for example

```
jar xvf foobar.jar foo.txt
```

Comment: Could be a plethora of reasons ;)